# How to flatten TIFF files when exporting from Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, tiff, flatten

I am trying to prepare some vector drawings for publication, of which the outlet in question require the images to be submitted as TIFFs. I have been doing the images in Adobe Illustrator, but I've noticed that when I do this it tends to flatten the vector artwork into a single layer, but not completely flatten the artwork. This tends to increase file size and causes some submissions to fail (i.e., the submission program thinks the single layer means the file is a multi-layer TIFF).

[image]

This is an example of what I mean. When the file is opened in Photoshop it still has a layer present (named whatever the vector document was), and this results in a larger file and some programs to not recognize the file as fully flattened.

To rectify this I have been going into Photoshop and manually flattening all vector drawings exported as TIFFs, but this slows down the workflow. I am trying to figure out if there is any way to export a file as a flattened TIFF from Illustrator without having to open and re-flatten it in Photoshop. I've seen several questions (i.e., [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82980/how-to-flatten-pdf-when-exporting-in-illustrator)), but they all discuss writing to .pdf, not writing to any of the other file formats. I've seen [this][3], which suggests there may not be a solution to the issue, but I am wondering if a solution has arisen since then.

Comment: What are your TIFF export settings/process? I can't replicate your issue here, but I am using a legacy version of AI. All tiff exports result in a flat "background layer" in Photoshop for me.

Comment: @Scott File -> Export As -> Export as TIFF. No option to flatten or anything. This may be a problem with newer versions of Illustrator, as I've seen mention that older versions of Illustrator had the option of `Flatten Image` but newer versions (CC and on) do not.

Comment: Could be a version issue.. I'm using CS6 where there is no "Export As..." just "Export". There's no "flatten" option... they just are flat after the export.

Comment: I can reproduce this with Illustrator CC 2018, I'm not on the latest version. Yeah looks like you will need to flatten in Photoshop if the software you are using is having trouble with a layered TIFF. As far as I know, there is no option to flatten the image on export from Illustrator CC I have to say however, that normally a layered TIFF is not a problem with most software. So, I wouldn't call this a bug with Illustrator as such.

Comment: @BillyKerr I get that there's no solution to this problem but at least in my case, not flattening the exported TIFFs in Photoshop is the difference between files being 10 mB versus <1 mB. The files end up being a lot more difficult to send via email or other services.

Comment: @user2352714 to be fair, a 10MB TIFF isn't  especially large for files used in graphic design. I've seen much larger files. In any case, usually you can use another format such as JPEG if file size is an issue. If you need to send a larger TIFF image, don't email it.  Use a file sharing site, upload it, and include the link in the email.  Perhaps speak to your print supplier, they may accept other common formats such as PDF.  In fact PDF is usually the standard format most publishers/print companies accept. I'd be very surprised if they don't accept PDF.